# how to relate to low resolution in my android widget?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I wrote an xml to my android widget.

I have tried it on Galaxy 3, and it was fine.

I now try it on Galaxy 1, and the resolution had messed everything up.

What it the way to relate to lower resolution in my XML?

I don't see separate folder for mdmi like for drawables.

Comment: You can create a folder layout-mdpi for mdpi screens

Comment: I meant for xml, not for drawables

Comment: there are no drawables in layout folder :) I also meant for xml. You can create a different xml layout for different fragmentations including screen resolution. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters)

Comment: Shouldn't weight solve this whole issue without creating few lyaout-xmls?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different layouts (not just drawables) for different [Qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters) (screen sizes, locales, ...etc) by creating `layout-<your Qualifier>` (`layout-mdpi` will be for `mdpi` screens).

Comment: what to use for Samsung Galaxy 1? Shouldn't weight solve this whole issue without creating few lyaout-xmls?

Comment: You can use screen size qualifiers instead (`layout-large` for S1 and `layout-xlarge` for S3)

Comment: Shouldn't weight solve this whole issue without creating few lyaout-xmls?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by resolution is messed up. Can you elaborate to see if your problem can be solved using weights?

Comment: see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922486/should-i-move-from-layout-weight-to-dip/17923403?noredirect=1#comment26187126_17923403