# should I move from layout_weight to dip?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have created a widget. I intentionally used `layout_weight`

so it would fit any screen size.

The widget is always spanned to 1X4.

I now look at different devices in the `graphic editor` and I see the weight doesn't help.

should I move to dip size?

The linear-layouts are spanned differently in relation to the background image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_widget_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_main"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_status_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_weight="0.21"
>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_icon_no_data"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <!--
                              Layout is necessary because the setVisibility of ProgressBar is not working 
                              through remote views in 2.1. So wrapped by this layout 
        -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/widget_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" >

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="39dp"
                android:indeterminateOnly="true"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout> <!-- Status image layout -->


    <!--
                            ========================================================================
                            * Information layout - contains all the texts 
                            ========================================================================
    -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_information"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.56"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\@ Home in"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_gravity="left" 

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" 
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />
    </LinearLayout> <!-- Information layout -->
    <!--
                            ========================================================================
                            * Action layout - action buttons container
                            ========================================================================
    -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_action"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_bt_drive_disabled" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Drive!"
            android:textColor="@color/disabled_white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout> <!-- Action layout -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious because single layout working perfectly on a normal screen sized device doesn't mean that it'll work the same way on large/xlarge sized screens. So create a folder inside res "layout-large" or "layout-xlarge" (depending on device screen size). Copy same layout into newly created folder and then make some changes to it, so it'll fit for large/xlarge screens as per your requirement. Also you may copy images into ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi to support multiple densities.

For more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: but shouldn't weight solve exactly this scaling issue? otherwise, what are weight for?

Comment: It should be. Can you please provide us your xml file, so that we can verify it?

Comment: Weights are working properly as they have to, perhaps I think there is problem with ImageView. Your ImageView's layout_width should not be wrap_content. Because if your Image is of wider width your ImageView's width will be increased. Put it to match_parent. One more thing is you've used android:src; sometimes using src can make padding/margin in the layout, so better change it to android:background and try. Alternatively you can put android:background to your layout instead of using ImageView. If this helps then we can go ahead.

Comment: I'll try. Another question: what's the expected behavior? 
I have a linearLayout with `orientation= horizontal`.

It has a child with `layout_weight=0.X` and also `layout_width=20dp`.

What will be the effective property?

Comment: 1) `ImageView's layout_width should not be wrap_content` but it is. Btw, the light blue photo is background (`android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_main"`)
2)but then you write" `Put it to match_parent`?? I'm confused. 3) isn't `android:src` the usuall way to add drawable?

Comment: suppose your orientation is horizontal and you've provided layout_weight, but when you try it on different screens the space it'll acquire will be different. Hence tough you provide weight, keep in mind that you're providing width! So assume that when weight space is less than 20dip still the width will be 20dip and for larger screens though weight space is more than 20dip you'll get only 20dip which will mess up your layout.

For ImageView if the image is of wider width and when you write wrap_content, sometimes you'll not get layout properly.

Comment: I have used android:src in my project. I was using 2 buttons for ImageView, but since I did that I was getting padding/margin for that frame/layout. So I changed it to background and it worked. I just suggested that nothing else :)

Comment: `background` as a property of `ImageView`? or as a property of its parent?

Comment: As a property of ImageView